# Supabase function doesn't do any calculations

Tags: postgresql, vuejs3, supabase, supabase-database, supabase-js

I have a function:

```
begin
    if pg_trigger_depth() <> 1 then
        return new;
    end if;
   new.rating = ROUND((new.total_score / new.total_reviews), 1);
   return new;
end;
```

This function must update column `rating` in table `route` every time I make an update on `route` table. Now the query if firing, `total_score` and `total_reviews` is getting updates, but column `rating` stays the same. I mean, there is no calculation on it and it's never change. No matter what's values I have in needed columns.

table `route` definition:

```
create table
  public.route (
    id bigint generated by default as identity not null,
    name text null,
    country text null,
    city text null,
    description text null,
    imageName text null,
    created_at timestamp with time zone null default now(),
    total_reviews numeric null,
    total_score numeric null,
    duration numeric not null default '30'::numeric,
    rating double precision null,
    isAdult boolean not null default false,
    constraint route_pkey primary key (id)
  ) tablespace pg_default;

create trigger update_route_rating_trigger
after insert
or
update on route for each row
execute function update_route_rating ();
```

RLS Policies on `route`:

---

Policy name: allow_update_on_route

Target roles: public

USING expression: true

WITH CHECK expression: true

---

Policy name: Authorized users can select from route table

Target roles: public

USING expression: (auth.role() = 'authenticated'::text)

---

Comment: You should be able to solve all of this using calculated column. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-generated-columns.html

Comment: In this case a generated column, as suggested, is the correct solution. But your initial process would have worked had you used the appropriate trigger. You used an **after row** trigger. *An after trigger **cannot** change data values*, to change values you must use a **before row** trigger. This after/before rule always applies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Belayer said, my solution won't work cuz it has `after row trigger` and ***an after trigger cannot change data values***, so that's why in this solution, I should have used `before row trigger`.

Also, the best working solution (IMHO) is a `generated-columns`, as @dshukertjr said.

Here is a link to generated columns doc for help: [postgresql.org/generated-columns](https://postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-generated-columns.html)